# How do I decrease the font size of specific elements in a date displayer

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website in html. What I want to do decrease the size of the hour, minute and second counter, but keep the size of the day, month and year counters. Splitting the 2 into separate id's doesn't seem to work and only shows the day, month and year. Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<head><title>My website</title>
<style type=text/css>
.clock {background-color: 000000; text-align: center; margin: 2px 0px 0px 1190px; font-size: 30px; position: fixed; border-radius: 10px;   color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff; border: 5px solid white;}
div {margin: 2px;}
body {background-color: 0d0d0d; font-family: "Vibur", sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="date" class="clock"></p>
  <script>
  setInterval(function(){
  date = new Date();
  sekundy = date.getSeconds();
  if (sekundy<10) sekundy = "0"+sekundy;
   minuty = date.getMinutes();
  if (minuty<10) minuty = "0"+minuty;
   godziny = date.getHours()
  if (godziny<10) godziny = "0"+godziny;
   dzien = date.getDay();
   data = date.getDate();
   miesiac = date.getMonth();
   rok = date.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = data+"."+((miesiac+1)%12)+"."+rok+"<br>"+godziny+" : "+minuty+" : "+sekundy;
  },1000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would gladly appreciate any help with figuring it out.

Comment: For some reason the snippet here doesn't work but the code itself works.

Comment: create multiple span with id and then assign it value: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Comment: @Ericgit How do I create multiple span with id and then assign it value though. I am not that great in html or javascript.

Comment: you should use the DOM API or simply said use javascript to create an element and assign value and attributes as desired. Read more here 
1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: @Кольо Пеев Could you give me an example of how it would or should look like?

Comment: `let randomElement = document.createElement('div');
randomElement.classList.add('random-class-name');
randomElement.setAttribute('id','para-1');
randomElement.innerHTML = 'Some random text here';
document.getElementsByClassName('the-parent-calss')[0].appendChild(randomElement)`

As you can see there are a lot of things you can do with JS and these are some of the most used ones, you can get an element by ID and skip the [0] part that refers to the index of an element in a node list returned by getElementsByClass